# Python, как удалить переменную из импортируемого файла?

Tags: python

```
# small.py
x = [0, 1]
y = [2, 3]
z = 7
...
```

Нужно импортировать переменные x, y, z... изменить их и сохранить обратно в тот же файл. Можно положить каждую переменную в свой файл и импортировать по отдельности:

```
# для переменной x
# small.py 
from small import x

x[0] += 5

with open('small.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write("x = ")
    print(x, file=file)
```

Но переменных может быть больше, я подумал, что если 30 переменных будут импортироваться из 30 файлов - это снизит быстродействие программы. Кажется будет лучше импортировать 30 переменных из одного файла. Можно ли изменить переменную, а затем как нибудь удалить её в импортируемом файле и добавить в него измененную версию переменной:

```
x[0] += 5

with open('small.py', 'a') as file:
    #удалить x из small.py???
    file.write("x = ")
    print(x, file=file)
```

Вопрос сформулирован предельно точно: это не разовая операция (изменить и сохранить).
Программа должна периодически получать входные данные обрабатывать и на их основе вносить изменения в свои переменные и так по кругу. Раз за разом.
Не понимаю почему все "плюют три раза через плечо" когда понимают, что надо изменять исходный код? Я ведь не инструкции хочу изменить, а файлик с переменными специально для этого предназначенный.

Comment: Не надо менять переменные в импортируемых модулях, это ОЧЕНЬ плохо. Правильнее хранить их в отдельном файле (не питоновском, а просто текстовом). Например, можно складывать все нужные переменные в словарь, сериализовать его с помощью JSON или pickle, и в таком виде хранить в текстовом файле.

Comment: Используйте XML или CSV файл.

Comment: Предполагаю, что нужно сохранить значения переменных, а не редактировать исходный код программы. Почитайте про [ошибку XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/192978), возможно это поможет улучшить вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем случае, для хранения значений переменных можно использовать обычные текстовые файлы. Принцип работы примерно следующий:

1. Инициализируем переменные значениями по умолчанию на случай, если файла с сохраненными значениями не существует (удалили, перенесли и т.п.).
2. Если файл существует, читаем из него значения.
3. Делаем что-то в программе, что может изменить значения.
4. Сохраняем новые значения в тот же файл.

---

Например:

main.py

```
filename = 'file.txt'
var1, var2, var3 = 1, 2, 3  # инициализируем значениями по умолчанию
separator = ','

if os.path.exists(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        var1, var2, var3 = map(int, file.read().split(separator))

# ... действия в рантайме, меняющие значения

with open(filename, 'w') as file:  # сохраняем все это добро в файл
    file.write(separator.join(map(str, [var1, var2, var3])))
```

Если же данных, которые надо сохранить, достаточно много, они имеют какие-то логические связи между собой или связаны с отдельными блоками программы, то разумнее использовать один из форматов json, yaml, xml, csv, ini и др. для того, чтобы эти данные как-то структурировать.